# Issue with simulation timing

Tags: system-verilog

Please help me to understand some simulator behavior related to timescale.
This is my top module:

```
module top;

//timeunit 1ns;
//timeprecision 1ps;

bit clk_62p5; // PCI write clock

always
    #8 clk_62p5++;

DPSRAM_64X4096 u_MEM (
    .clka(clk_62p5),
    ….
);

…

endmodule 

`timescale 1 ns/1 ps

module DPSRAM_64X4096 (…);
…
endmodule
```

This is my simulation script:

```
irun \
 …
    -timescale 1ns/1ps \
    …
```

When I run the simulation, I see that the `clk_62p5` clock period is 16ps and not 16ns.  Can you explain why I have this behavior?

A 2nd question: what is the difference between `timeunit`, `timeprecision` and `timescale`?

Comment: To not answer your first question: I could not reproduce your problem. Here is [my attempt](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/aP_). Please could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, I notice you have written  `timescale 1 ns/1 ps . This should be  `timescale 1ns/1ps . Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: Yes I think you should remove the spaces in `timescale` and check again

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question:

`timescale is a *compiler directive*. Using compiler directives can cause *compile order dependencies*, that is different behaviour or problems that are caused by the actual order you compile your files in. Suppose you have three files:

```
fileA.v   `timescale 1ns/1ps
fileB.v   `timescale 10ns/10ps
fileC.v   // no timescale directive
```

If you compile in this order

```
fileA.v fileB.v fileC.v
```

then the precision will be 1ps - the smallest the compile found - the timeunit for each file will be:

```
fileA.v  1ns   because of the `timescale directive
fileB.v  10ns  because of the `timescale directive
fileC.v  10ns  because the `timescale directive from fileB.v continues to have an effect
```

If you compile in this order

```
fileA.v fileC.v fileB.v
```

then the precision will be 1ps - the smallest the compile found - the timeunit for each file will be:

```
fileA.v  1ns   because of the `timescale directive
fileB.v  10ns  because of the `timescale directive
fileC.v  1ns   because the `timescale directive from fileA.v continues to have an effect
```

If you compile in this order

```
fileC.v fileA.v fileB.v
```

then you will get an error, because it is illegal to have a file with no `timescale` directive appearing before any file with a `timescale` directive. (Though it is OK if no file has a `timescale directive).

`timeunit` and `timeprecision` are newer, System-Verilog ways of achieving the same thing. As they are not compiler directives, they do not suffer from the related problems. They only apply to the scope ($unit/package/module/program/interface) that they are used in (and must come first in that scope).

If you use `timeunit` and `timeprecision` as well as a timescale directive, then `timeunit` and `timeprecision` take priority.